# How to validate functions with variable parameters in TurboGears?

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, turbogears

For functions with fixed number of parameters validations works fine,
Eg:

```
@validate(validators= {'foo': bar })
def func(self, foo=None):
    pass
```

However I am facing difficulty to validate a function with unknown number of parameters, like for example

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    '''do something'''
    pass
```

Any idea what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Do arguments have any rule? Like they are all of the same type repeated or things like that?

TurboGears2 actually accepts anything with a `validate` method as the validator. So you can use a **Formencode** Schema as validator http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/turbogears/validation.html#schema-validation or you can roll your own class and raise a `TGValidationError` from it ( http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/classes.html#tg.validation.TGValidationError ).